# Block the operator from receiving calls without being paused

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

In my company we are using Asterisk 15, and would like to know if it is possible without the operator to pause, he only receive calls after a command.

To explain further, we use a dialer system, and the operator can only receive another call after registering the current call.
We have a websocket that is AMI connected with Asterisk that can send these commands.

I thought about pausing the operator, but this would lead to reporting complications.

Grateful to all who are willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use queue+dynamic agents.

There are no problem logon/logoff agent automatically as needed using external script.

Just do fake call and standart scripts for logon/logoff.

Comment: I also can't logoff the operator, we have reports of this that would be compromised.
I'm guessing the only way out is to pause it yourself, and validate the break pause report.

Comment: Freepbx do dialling via context. So just change context then to check some astdb variable or hire someone to do that.